# What does this code mean?`Its for a wcf service call

Tags: c#, wcf

I have this following code. Which is used to call a wcf service async.  I cant figure out what the handler does and the args or why it is used(How can i use it). I know that the method returns a task and i use this task to await in the method it is called from. Any help will be appreciated.

```
  public Task<List<Student>> GetStudents()
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<List<Student>>();
        EventHandler<GetStudentsCompletedEventArgs> handler = null;
        handler = (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (args.UserState == tcs)
            {
                service.GetStudentsCompleted -= handler;
                if (args.Error != null)
                {
                    tcs.TrySetException(args.Error);
                }
                else if (args.Cancelled)
                {
                    tcs.TrySetCanceled();
                }
                else
                {
                    tcs.TrySetResult(args.Result);
                }

            }
        };

        service.GetStudentsCompleted += handler;
        service.GetStudentsAsync(tcs);

        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code converts from the Event Asynchronous Pattern[(EAP)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wewwczdw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)(which is exposed by the WCF client) to a task([TAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).